# re-write a for loop function in a simpler way?

Tags: string, list

I'm new to the python and I was just wondering if this could be rewritten in a simpler way and without using for loops? The expected value example for this function is given below the code.

```py
def valid_words(dictionary, sentence):
    x =sentence.split()
    y = dictionary.split()
    newlist = []

    for i in x:
      for j in y:
         if i == j:
            newlist.append(i)
    return newlist
```

My function should take in 2 strings: one containing valid words, and another containing potential words. The output should be a list of words which are present in both strings, and are exact matches as delimited by whitespace.

For example, valid words `"a aa apple banana pear strawberry mango"` and potential words`"hello mango and banana yum apple!"` would return `["mango", "banana"]`

Note that `"apple!"` isn't matched as a valid word due to the exclamation mark being part of the word.

Comment: Does your code already work and you’re trying to improve it, or are you trying to solve a specific problem with it?

Comment: Yes the code works but I want to know if the same is possible without using the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Split both string at whitespace, converting them each into a `set`. A set is like a list, except there cannot be multiples of the same value and the order is not kept track of.
2. Return the union of these 2 sets. Think of this as like making a Venn Diagram.

Note that I am choosing to *not* use the word `dictionary` for my variable name, since in Python that has a special meaning.

```py
def valid_words(valid, potential):
    return list(set(valid.split()) & set(potential.split()))
```